# $validator ignores $setValidity in Password Form

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-forms

I have a validator

```
model.$validators.passwordMatch = function (modelValue) {
    var repeatPasswordIsValid = (/*some test*/);

    return repeatPasswordIsValid;
};
```

And from another place I test something else set the validity of the same form

```
repeatPasswordModel.$setValidity('passwordMatch', true);
```

The problem is that `$setValidity` is completely ignored and only the validator's test is applied to the form validity. If is setValidity to true, and the validator return false, then it will be false. I would like it to override and to be true, am I missing something?

This is the full code of the directive: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgKmLJ

Comment: If you set validity `true` and then subsequently set it `false`, why would you expect it to stay `true`?

Comment: I know, but for some reason I thought that setting validity from other place will override the testing function of `passwordMatch`. Is there a way to set the same validator from another place and another test, that is not related to what is inside the validation function?

Comment: A codepen without HTML or CSS is not much use. Please post the HTML and explain what you are trying to accomplish. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).